# Yii2 - ActiveDataProvider "count" error when using a calculated field

Tags: yii2

I am trying to filter by a calculated column "age". I have tried the following:

```
public $age;

public function search($params)
{
    $query = Profile::find();
    $query->select = ['*', 'age' => 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE())'];

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'between', 'age', $this->age_min, $this->age_max,
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'age' in 'where
>   clause' The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `profile`
>   WHERE `age` BETWEEN '41' AND '62'

So I think what's happening is, it is trying to retrieve a count of matching records (for the ListView widget) but it's not taking in to account my custom "select" statement.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you should use:

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'between', 
    new Expression('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE())'), 
    $this->age_min, 
    $this->age_max,
]);
```

There is no reason for use `HAVING` here, and it may create problems if you use it on query without `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Suppose I want to `ORDER BY` my calculated age column, how can I do this using `orderBy()`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I need to use `andFilterHaving()` instead of `andFilterWhere()` if I want to query a calculated column.